# py2neo - neokit usage in script

Tags: python, py2neo

I want to use neokit to manage my Neo4J store from a script.
I'm using Windows 7, Python 3.5.2 (Anaconda 4.1.1) and py2neo v3.1.2.
Neo4J is community version 3.0.4.
This is my code:

```
import neokit
home="C:\\neo4j-community-3.0.4"
gs=neokit.GraphServer(home=home)
```

Some commands work fine, e.g.

```
gs.control_script  # returns C:\\neo4j-community-3.0.4\\bin\\neo4j
a=gs.config('dbms.active_database') # Returns name of active database
gs.stop() # To stop the server.
```

However other commands return with an error message `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'running'`, line 515 in neokit.py. Examples are:

```
gs.start()
gs.http_port
gs.running()
```

Do I need some additional configuration?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neokit doesn't support Windows, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've made 2 small changes on neokit: Line 515 - replace `p = int(line.rpartition(" ")[-1])` with `p = line`, and in class GraphServerV3, property http_port(self) remove test for self.running, code starts with ´if port is None:` now. This is sufficient for start(), stop(), running() to execute successfully and does the job for now.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. If you want to submit a PR that allows the code to run on Both Windows and Linux, I'll happily roll that into the library.